# css opacity transition affecting text

Tags: html, css

i have an issue on my nav bar..trying to cpy the "Dragon interactive" nav only with html and css (still new ont this so i can not handel javascript or jquery yet!!).
since the transition on gradient background is not availble on css i tryed the opacity...things seem working wel for background but the navbar text go away when mouse hover!! any idea guys how to overcome this issue simply!!(css only :p)
html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container"><ul class="menu" rel="sam1">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Acceuil</a></li>
    <li><a href="service.html"><span>Services</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">assistance</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ats.dz" target='_blank'>Produits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background : #464646;
background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(168,168,168)), to(rgb(69,69,69)));
background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(168,168,168), rgb(69,69,69));
border-top: 0px solid #939393;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-left:150px;

}

ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

 ul.menu {
height: 70px;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
float:left;
}

 ul.menu li {
list-style: none;
float:left;
height: 69px;
text-align: center;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 100%, 10, 50% 50%, 90, from(rgba(31,169,244,1)), to(rgba(0,28,78, 1)) );
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center 80px 45deg, circle cover, rgba(31,169,244,1) 0%, rgba(0,28,78, 1) 100%);

}

ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 0 20px;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
text-align: center;
line-height: 69px;
background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(168,168,168)), to(rgb(69,69,69)));
background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(168,168,168), rgb(69,69,69));
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;
-moz-transition-property: opacity;
-moz-transition-duration: 1.5s;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size:13px;
opacity:1;
}

ul li a:hover {
opacity:0;

 }

 ul li.active a{
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 100%, 10, 50% 50%, 90, from(rgba(31,169,244,1)), to(rgba(0,28,78, 1)) );
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center 80px 45deg, circle cover, rgba(31,169,244,1) 0%, rgba(0,28,78, 1) 100%);
color:#fff;
 }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this happens because of this line:

```
ul li a:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Ok...opacity:0 will make the text goes none...how can i fix it?

Comment: Just set it to (only problem is that then there is no animation):

`ul li a:hover  {
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 100%, 10, 50% 50%, 90, from(rgba(31,169,244,1)), to(rgba(0,28,78, 1)) );
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center 80px 45deg, circle cover, rgba(31,169,244,1) 0%, rgba(0,28,78, 1) 100%);
color:#fff;
 }`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Au6bj6X3g2drYuj3KmsY?p=preview
Here with animations. Using :before pseudo to achieve this.

Comment: ookkkkkkkkay guys..i got it working with your help!! thank you ... check the final working codes here if anyone need it for his own!!
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/GKn9ybbm1LxXqjWzCfmn?p=preview)